# Error Sending Email through SMTPClient in Pharo smalltalk

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

```
 | message sender recipients |
  message := 'From: Me <myemail@gmail.com>
  To: You <otheremail@gmail.com>
   Subject: Simple Mail from pharo

    This is a test mail'.
  sender := 'myemail@gmail.com'.
  recipients := #('your@gmail.com').
SMTPClient
deliverMailFrom: sender
to: recipients
text: message
usingServer: 'smtp.gmail.com'
```

This code gives me a Telnetprotocol error.

I tired ZdcSecureSMTPClient class it works fine.

So My question here is can i send email without using password as ZdcSecureSMTPClient uses password

Answer (score 1):

You can't send through google's servers without logging in. Actually, I don't think you can send in plain-text, just over SSL.